# WCF service Unable to establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority

Tags: wcf, soap, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF service that I want to use to connect to an external provider's API. The Client constructor in my service looks like this:

```
public partial class SomePortTypeClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<SomeService.ClientPortType>, SomeService.SomePortType
    {
        static partial void ConfigureEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials clientCredentials);

        public SomePortTypeClient(string endpointUrl, TimeSpan timeout, string username, string password) :
        base(SomePortTypeClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(timeout), SomePortTypeClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointUrl))
        {
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;          
            this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.Root, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "11au2i3h3ir3o1748905");
        }
```

The client includes a https binding like this:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;

            var integerMaxValue = int.MaxValue;
            httpsBinding.MaxBufferSize = integerMaxValue;
            httpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = integerMaxValue;
            httpsBinding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            httpsBinding.AllowCookies = true;

            httpsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.CloseTimeout = timeout;

            return httpsBinding;
        }
```

And then the actual implementation of the client and calling the endpoint:

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

SomePortTypeClient someClient = new SomePortTypeClient("https://endpointURL", duration, "username", "password");

var response = someClient.someMethod(someParameter).Result;
```

I created a CSR in Windows cert manager, and the external provider provided the certificates shown in the picture below which I have imported both into my personal and root store on my local machine. It is the top certificate that I use "SetCertificate" on and locate by thumbprint in my client constructor. This certifiate is linked to the Intermediate CA which is again linked to the Root CA.

[image]

So! When I run the code and try to call the endpoint I get the following error:

[image]

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to certificates and WCF services, so I'm not sure what could be wrong here. I have tried using the three different certificates, both from the personal and the root store. I have also tried using just basic authentication and none while also setting the username, password and certificate. The service I'm trying to call is a SOAP service.

UPDATE: It seems the certificate was not signed with the correct private key. I reimported the certificate and the error disappeard, however now I'm getting a new error that just says `A security error was encountered when verifying the message`. I've looked around and it seems this is often caused by a time difference between the client/server. I'm not sure how to solve this either, so any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I enabled WCF tracing, here is the stack trace for the exception:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-11-25T07:12:21.8768782Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="ConsoleApp1" ProcessID="22044" ThreadID="6" /><Channel /><Computer>LAPTOP-U7FDFSNI</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/System-ServiceModel-Diagnostics-ThrowingException</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>ConsoleApp1.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'URI'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.OnGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(Exception E)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckWriteSideResponseProcessing()
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.WriteCallDone(ConnectStream stream, ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.IOError(Exception exception, Boolean willThrow)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.HandleWriteHeadersException(Exception e, WebExceptionStatus error)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ResumeIOWorker(Object result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.WakeupPendingIO(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.FinishHandshake(Exception e, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32 result)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'URI'. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Using certificate to authenticate client needs to establish mutual trust relationship between client and server. Does your server trust the certificate provided by the client? Whether it is already installed on the server. In addition, we can confirm whether the trust relationship to the server has been established by accessing the metadata URL of the service in the browser of the client. If trusted, the browser address bar is marked with a security lock.